# ¿Cómo ejecutar codigo PHP cada cierto tiempo?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Estoy creando un sitio web de al momento de iniciar sesión se genera un session_id, esta información es insertada en la BD, todo esto lo hago para si una persona en un navegador ingresa con su usuario y contraseña lo deja navegar en el sitio sin problema, pero si otra persona intenta acceder con las mismas credenciales, entonces el sistema hará que solamente deje la ultima sesión abierta y bote la de la sesión a la primer persona que tuvo acceso, para que solo exista una sesión por usuario.
El problema es que  esta validación de sesiones se hace cuando refresca la pagina o cambia a otra pagina, lo que quiero hacer es que este bloque de codigo se ejecute cada cierto tiempo, para que la primer sesión la bote automáticamente y no esperar a que el usuario refresque o cambie de pagina. Leí que con ajax se puede hacer, mi codigo es el siguiente:

Código js:

```
<script>
$(function() { 
    cron(); // Lanzo cron la primera vez
    function cron() {
        $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            url: "index.php", 
            data: {
                action: 1
            }
        }).done(function(msg) {
            console.log(msg);
        });
    }
    setInterval(function() {
        cron();
    }, 10000); // Lanzará la petición cada 10 segundos
});
```

Este es mi codigo php:

```
if(isset($_POST["action"])) { // Se pasa una acción
    switch(sprintf("%d", $_POST["action"])) { // ¿Qué acción?
        case 1:
            cerrar();
            echo "Tarea completada!";
            break;
        default:
            echo "Error: Falta una acción";
    }
}
function cerrar(){
    $ses = session_id();
    $connection_s = new sesionunica();
    $userById = $connection_s->getUsers($_SESSION["id_user"]);
    if ($userById["id_sesion"] <> $ses){
        echo"<script>location.href='logout.php';</script>"; 
    }
}
```

Lo que trato de hacer con esto es que cada 10s ejecute el script de ajax, después evalué la acción y ejecute la función llamada cerrar, cuando la ejecute que me dirija a la pagina logout.php, hasta el momento no me redirige a la pagina dada. ¿Alguna idea de como solucionar esto?

Comment: has probado a hacer la llamada post (con postman, por ej) para ver que resultado te da el PHP? mas que nada para confirmar que si envias un 1 te escribe lo de "tarea completada"

Comment: Revisa el código de [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44948894/how-to-use-header-redirect-in-php-ajax-call-in-pure-javascript).

Comment: Puede utilizar META REFRESH

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En este if() en lugar de devolver un script solo devuelva un echo "success", seria algo así:

```
if ($userById["id_sesion"] <> $ses) {
    echo "success"; 
}
```

y en el Ajax del cliente seria algo así:

```
$.ajax({
  method: "POST",
  url: "index.php", 
  data: { action: 1 }
  })
.done(function(msg) {
  console.log(msg);

  if( msg == 'success' ) {  // Valida si el server devolvió 'success'
    location.href='logout.php';
  }
});
```

y por ultimo en tu código de devolución de PHP elimina esto

```
echo "Tarea completada!";
```

esto impediría que desde el navegador se leyera success

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, estuve un tiempo fuera, pero al probarla me funciono, Gracias.